# Order to Cash public dataset

Tags: data-request, finance, opencorporates

I am currently working on a project where I need access to an Order to Cash(O2C) and Purchase to Pay (P2P) dataset. I managed to get a P2P dataset from [here](https://icpmconference.org/2019/icpm-2019/contests-challenges/bpi-challenge-2019/), but am struggling to data for O2C. I've gone through kaggle/google datasets as well as several govt databanks but without any success. Any ideas/help regarding locating an O2C/another P2P dataset would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[OCBC - A NEW MODELING LANGUAGE](https://www.win.tue.nl/ocbc/cases/order_to_cash.html)

Order to cash (OTC or O2C) business process which is a very typical business process that involves receiving and fulfilling customer requests for goods or services.

You can download this case study dataset from [the Direct Download Link](https://www.win.tue.nl/ocbc/experiments/CaseStudy.zip)